# Google drive desktop authentication fail

Tags: drive

On one of my machines google drive desktop has stopped working.

I have tried the many options here https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2565956?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop to no avail.

After sign-in I get the dialog message "Can’t launch Drive for desktop
Something went wrong and Drive for desktop couldn’t launch. To launch Drive for desktop, try restarting the application."

In the drivefs log file I see this authentication failure. Any idea how to resolve?

> 2023-07-14T08:04:13.038ZI [15964:CurlWorker0] curl_api.cc:1052:LogCurlInfo == Info: schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_REVOCATION_STATUS_UNKNOWN
> 2023-07-14T08:04:13.042ZI [15964:CurlWorker0] curl_api.cc:1052:LogCurlInfo == Info: Closing connection 0
> 2023-07-14T08:04:13.042ZI [15964:CurlWorker0] curl_api.cc:1052:LogCurlInfo == Info: schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with [www.googleapis.com](http://www.googleapis.com) port 443
> 2023-07-14T08:04:13.042ZE [19888:CurlWorker0] curl_api.cc:131:StatusFromCurlCode Unsupported curl code 60, mapping to NETWORK_TRANSPORT_ERROR: schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_REVOCATION_STATUS_UNKNOWN
> 2023-07-14T08:04:13.043ZE [15964:CurlWorker0] curl_api.cc:131:StatusFromCurlCode Unsupported curl code 60, mapping to NETWORK_TRANSPORT_ERROR: schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_REVOCATION_STATUS_UNKNOWN
> 2023-07-14T08:04:13.044ZE [8684:core_new_user] oauth_credential.cc:311:operator() Failed to exchange auth code. Transport error: drive::ds::Status::NETWORK_TRANSPORT_ERROR
> 2023-07-14T08:04:13.047ZE [8684:core_new_user] account_context.cc:548:operator() UNKNOWN: Failed to authenticate account [type.googleapis.com/drive.ds.Status='NETWORK_TRANSPORT_ERROR']
> === Source Location Trace: ===
> apps/drive/fs/account_context.cc:545

> 2023-07-14T08:04:13.047ZE [3476:MetricsTransportThread] legacy_metrics_transport.cc:206:SendRequest Request failed: drive::ds::Status::NETWORK_TRANSPORT_ERROR
> 2023-07-14T08:04:13.047ZI [3476:MetricsTransportThread] legacy_metrics_transport.cc:408:ProcessRequestsOnBackgroundThread Metrics failed to send, drive::ds::Status::NETWORK_TRANSPORT_ERROR
> 2023-07-14T08:04:13.048ZE [20104:NonCelloThread] client.cc:4118:StartAccountAuthComplete Account context authorization failed with error: UNKNOWN: Failed to authenticate account [type.googleapis.com/drive.ds.Status='NETWORK_TRANSPORT_ERROR']
> === Source Location Trace: ===
> apps/drive/fs/account_context.cc:545

> 2023-07-14T08:04:13.063ZI [20104:NonCelloThread] drive_fs.cc:414:operator() Startup tracing disabled
> 2023-07-14T08:04:13.063ZI [18368:trace_writer_thread] instrumentation.cc:645:operator() Writing Chrome Trace to C:\Users\ruper\AppData\Local\Google\DriveFS\Logs\startup_trace_2023-07-14T08_04_13.json
> 2023-07-14T08:04:13.064ZI [18368:trace_writer_thread] instrumentation.cc:647:operator() Trace successfully written
> 2023-07-14T08:04:18.903ZI [20104:NonCelloThread] notification_dialog.cc:133:OnQuery button_clicked { button_index: 0 checkbox_checked: false }
> 2023-07-14T08:04:18.903ZI [20104:NonCelloThread] client.cc:2536:StopAllAccounts StopAllAccounts with SUCCESSFUL_EXIT initiated from notification_handler.cc:558:operator()
> 2023-07-14T08:04:19.439ZI [20104:NonCelloThread] client.cc:2822:QuitUILoop Quitting UI loop as requested from client.cc:2553:SilentQuit
> 2023-07-14T08:04:19.473ZI [20104:NonCelloThread] drive_fs.cc:670:RunDriveFS Return code: SUCCESSFUL_EXIT
> 2023-07-14T08:04:19.473ZI [20104:NonCelloThread] ipc_server_manager.cc:49:~IpcServerManager Quitting the IPC thread
> 2023-07-14T08:04:19.473ZI [20104:NonCelloThread] ipc_server_manager.cc:52:~IpcServerManager IPC thread destroyed.